# 3+ hop port forwarding, iptables and two windows machines (1 windows VM), Qubes OS

Tags: linux, windows, iptables, routing, forwarding

Okay, I have the following setup (everything except last hop is VMs inside QubesOS, but linux networking considerations presumably apply)

-- denotes "virtual ethernet card" connection

== denotes a physical ethernet card connection (crossover cable from Qubes host physical NIC to windows XP box)

Windows-7-VM--ProxyVM--NIChostVM==WindowsXP-USB-share

What I want is passing a usb through Fabulatech's USB sharing software
Port is 33000

So what I need to do is to have iptables rules to pass traffic correctly between Win-7 VM and the WindowsXP-USB-share

For the life of mine I can't figure it out.

I can get traffic going if I passthrough the NIC to ProxyVM

Windows-7-VM--ProxyVM==WindowsXP-USB-share

In that simplified setup all it takes is the following rules in ProxyVM:

```
ifconfig enp0s0f6 up

ifconfig enp0s0f6 192.169.1.2

ifconfig eth1 netmask 255.255.255.0

DNAT --to-destination 10.137.77.2:33000
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.137.4.22 -d 192.169.1.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -d 10.137.4.22 -s 192.169.1.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -s 192.169.1.1 -d 192.169.1.2 -j ACCEPT
```

However, trying to come up with something that would work in case of a longer machine chain results in replies being lost (and odd misbehavior of devices being shared)

Of course I could live with NIC being passed through to proxyvm but given it connects to a windows XP machine I'd rather it sit in a separate VM.

Oh, and experiments suggest that Fabulatech's stuff uses source/destination IP for some rudimentary authentication (even if authentication is disabled)

So what I need is the following:

Pass port 33000 through a chain of four machines that goes like

```
(Windows 7)-(default gateway, aka Linux host 1)-(linux-host-2)
                                                     |
                                                     |
                      [crossover link on a dedicated NIC of Linux host 2] 
                                       |
                                       |
                               (windows XP host)
```

in such a manner that Windows XP host "sees" Windows 7's IP as "source" and windows 7 sees windows XP's IP as "source IP" in all replies.

It would probably involve some SNAT and policy routing and frankly I am out of my wits.

P.S.:

Windows 7 IP is 10.137.4.22

linux host 1 is acting as default gateway for windows 7 and linux-host-2

linux host 2 IP is 10.137.4.4

the NIC for XP's connection is connected to linux host 2
it's IP is 192.169.1.2

Windows XP's IP is 192.169.1.1

Comment: Is there any reason you are NATing these networks? Why not just turn on ip routing on the kernel and pass the traffic through unadulterated? Then it is only a matter of a couple static routes and iptables rules. Typically you wouldn't NAT internal private networks like this.

Comment: Also, if your goal is for one machine to "see" the IP address of the other distant machine. That is impossible with NAT. One of the basic principals of NAT is that it hides IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The more I look at this your problem is with missing static routes. Let's be clear NAT rules are not needed to accomplish this.

But, the reason why it works with just VMProxy in the middle is because all the machines know how to find each other. XP ha a default gateway of VM proxy. Windows 7 has a default gateway to other VMProxy interface. VMProxy is directly connected to both networks and voila, they can communicate.

When adding more machines that have multiple interfaces you have to set static routes. Any system that needs to communicate with a network that is not directly connected and is not reachable via the default gateway will need a static route setup that says, if you want to reach x.x.x.x network the next hop is y.y.y.y.  y.y.y.y is the IP address of the next closest interface that can reach the destination network.

I'd be more specific but you left out at least one IP address in your info.